# Laravel Mock Facade shouldReceive Not Working As Intended

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, mockery

This test fails because it will never pass the `Auth::attempt()` function call. I put a `dd()` statement to prove that it won't make it.

If I remove the two `Auth::shouldReceive()` the code will run the first `dd()` statement.

If I keep even one `Auth::shouldReceive()` the first `dd()` statement will never get called.

If I add `->twice()` instead of `->once()` there are no errors thrown which is odd because it should complain that it has only been called once.

If I place a `dd()` statement at the first line of the controller it does not run until I remove the `Auth::shouldReceive()` functions.

I must be something silly that I'm not getting because I've looked over many tutorials.

Controller

```
public function postLogin() {
    $email = Input::get('email');
    $password = Input::get('password');
    dd('Does not make it to this line with auth::shouldReceive() in the test');
    if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>$email, 'password'=>$password))) {
        dd("Doesn't make it here either with auth::shouldReceive() mock.");
        $user = Auth::user();
        Session::put('user_timezone', $user->user_timezone);
        return Redirect::to('user/dashboard')->with('message', 'You are now logged in!');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('user/login')->with('message', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect')->withInput();
    }
}
```

Test

```
public function testUserTimezoneSessionVariableIsSetAfterLogin()
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->user_timezone = 'America/New_York';
    $user->email = 'test@test.com';
    $user->password = 'test';

    $formData = [
        'email' => 'test@test.com',
        'password' => '123',
    ];

    \Auth::shouldReceive('attempt')->once()->with($formData)->andReturn(true);
    \Auth::shouldReceive('user')->once()->andReturn($user);

    $response = $this->call('POST', '/user/login', $formData);
    $this->assertResponseStatus($response->getStatusCode());


    $this->assertSessionHas('user_timezone');
}
```

Comment: Do you have any middleware on this route?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Just what ever the stock Laravel application has enabled in the Kernel.php file.

Comment: Just an idea, but `Auth::user()` might called by some of the internals. Change `once()` to `zeroOrMoreTimes()` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Same result as before the code in the controller isn't called at all. I tried with a `dd()` statement at the top and it doesn't execute.

Comment: Maybe this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24033017/919933

Comment: Thank you for replying Rodrigo. In a post below I forgot to add parent::construct() in the constructor of my controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had `parent::construct()` in the constructor of my UserController. Apparently this causes issues with mocks.

I assumed this was necessary to have `parent::construct()` because I had a custom constructor in UserController.